# Writing a shell script (or something similar) that will execute some commands

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

For my work I use an app called Sublime Text to edit website documents. To open my project in sublime text I drag the folder above the icon and it opens it up in sublime text.

My next step is to run a nodejs script, and after it's run open chrome and navigate to a local url.

My question is - how can I automate that process - meaning I will have a script that I run (command line is fine) that will open the project in sublime text, run the nodejs script (which starts a local web server), open safari to a url.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible. The two best options for stitching together Mac applications are AppleScript and Automator.

Given your steps, consider exploring the included Automator application: **Applications > Automator.app**

Apple's [Mac Basics: Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488) support note is a good starting point.

The following **Actions** are likely to help:

- **Display Webpages** for opening your default browser and showing a URL
- **Run Shell Script** for interacting with [node.js](http://nodejs.org)
- **Open Finder Items** for opening documents in [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com)

[image: Automator on OS X 10.9]

Answer (score 4):

You can write a bash script. Bash script is like windows batch file.

Here is a little example. Open sublime text and type in:

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a "Sublime Text 2"
node scriptname.js
open -a "Safari" http://localhost
```

Save it as script.sh

Then open the terminal and navigate to script folder. Type in next command and hit enter:

```
chmod u+x script.sh
```

then run it:

```
./script.sh
```

More at bash scripts [here](http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial) and [here](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/unix/bash-tute.html).

Comment: this is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be fine:

```
open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/ Folder/ && node script.js && open http://localhost:80
```

Replace Folder/ with folder path and script to the nodejs script path.

Comment: how do I run this? is there some batch file for mac?

Comment: Simply paste it in Terminal, or as already explained in the other answer save it in a .sh file.

Comment: of course, make sure to alias this for ease of use in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the script with a .command extension: this gives you a file you can "double-click" to open it as an application.

Both way's (use .sh or .command as an extension), you have to make the script executable with chmod in Terminal: `chmod u+x ~/MyScript.sh`.

Comment: excellent tip! i've been using a mac and scripting for many years and have yet to hear this one. granted, i try to never use the mouse, but it is still an interesting alternative.