# How can I make macOS require my password once per day, before Touch ID?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, security, password, touch-id

My Mac is configured with Touch ID and most of the time I want that, but I want to configure a policy such that the first time I wake it up after 6 AM it requires my password, or such that it requires my password once every 24 hours.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: First off..TouchID is an authentication *mechanism*  - it's the biological equivalent of a password - it's not macOS' authentication *system*.   So, the question, if I understand it correctly is that you want to *authenticate* every day at 6AM.  Correct?  If so, why?  Do you have your Security Settings configured to require a password after so many mins of sleep/screen saver?  What are you hoping to accomplish that having your Mac require a password after 24hours that *isn't* accomplished with the built in password after sleep/screen saver?

Answer (score 3):

After some [research](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/afk3o0/comment/edzp5f4), I learned that macOS has a utility called `bioutil` that may do what you want.

To disable TouchID after 24 hours, you can run this one-line command:

```sh
sudo bioutil -ws -o 86400  # require a password after 24 hours
```

To disable TouchID manually for the night, you can run a command to disable TouchID for unlock, and another to re-enable it. In my experience, this should make macOS require a password once at unlock time before re-enabling TouchID for later unlocks.

The commands to *manually* require a password for TouchID are as follows:

```sh
sudo bioutil -ws -u 0  # disables TouchID for unlock
sudo bioutil -ws -u 1  # enables TouchID for unlock
```

You can [write a shell script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121038) to do this for you. See `man bioutil` in the terminal for more things you can do with it!

Bonus: macOS Monterey has a [Shortcuts app](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-use-shortcuts-app-on-mac/) which you can use to make a menu bar item to run this.

Answer (score 2):

If you've not already set your security preferences to require a password after some amount of sleep and/or screensaver, there's really no benefit to forcing a login at the beginning of the day - it's been vulnerable all that time and locking it at 6:00am only to be unlocked again for the rest of the day makes it a moot security policy.

But, if you want to force an authentication event every day at 6:00am you'll need to do the following:

- write a bash script that locks the computer.  There are two methods...

  - `pmset`
  - `CGSession`
- have that script run every day at a prescribed time using `launchd`

**A note about the scripts/terminal commands**

- I encourage you to test them out first before handing them over to `launchd`.  Just type out the command(s) in Terminal to see if they work.
- You must set the script to be executable by using the command `chmod +x <nameofscript>` or this won't work at all.

---

### Using pmset

Assuming that you have "Require Password" after some amount of time after you lock the screen or activate your screen saver, you can use the following command in a bash script to sleep your computer once per day:

```
pmset sleepnow
```

The script can be saved in `~/Library/Scripts` and can be called whatever you like.  Let's use `sleep1.sh` for this example

```
#!/bin/bash
# 
/usr/bin/pmset sleepnow
```

Run that script and your Mac will immediately go to sleep and if you have a password set, depending on the time interval you set, once you wake it, it will ask you for a password.

### Using CGSession

This uses the "[Fast User Switching](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/switch-quickly-between-users-mchlp2439/mac)" mechanism to lock your desktop.  You can test it out by issuing the following command:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend
```

When you execute this command, your desktop will be locked and you should be greeted with a login screen where you have to select a user (if you have multiple) or enter a username and password.

The script, like the previous example can be saved in `~/Library/Scripts` and can also be called whatever you like.  Let's use `sleep2.sh` for this example.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Get User ID
id=$(id -u <username>

# Put the system to sleep but switch to current user
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend -switchToUserID $id
```

**Note:** If you intend to do this for all logged in users (if you *have* multiple users on your machine), change the `id` line to look like this:

```
id=$(id -u `whoami`)
```

This will ensure that the command uses the user id of the *currently logged in user*.

### Using `launchd` to make this run every day

To get this to run every day, we need to have an daemon kick it off at a prescribed time.  macOS comes with such a tool and it's called `launchd`.  I go into further detail about it in the post 
[launchd plist format for running a command at a specific time on a weekday](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271).  However, for our purposes here, we'll use a basic `.plist` to start this script every morning.  I like to use the file naming convention `com.user.XXXX.plist`  Replace "XXX" with whatever you like, for this example, I'm using `com.user.lockmachine.plist`.

Also be sure to reference the script you plan to use, `script1.sh` or `script2.sh`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.lockmachine</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/<username>/Library/Scripts/script1.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>6</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

#### How do you want to run this daemon?

Where you put the script matters.  See the linked post for more details, but decide if you want this to be for just you or for all users.  Here's a quick summary:

- Just you - put it in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`
- For all users - put it in `/Library/LaunchAgents`

Then *from the directory where you put the newly created `.plist`*, load it using `launchctl`

```
sudo lauchctl load com.user.lockmachine.plist
```

### Authenticate away!

You're done.  Once per day at 6AM your machine will be forced to go to sleep or have the session switched (depending on the script you selected) where you'll be forced to *authenticate*.  There's no point in doing this on login or at boot because if you're this concerned about security, you wouldn't have auto login enabled bypassing authentication.

Answer (score 1):

macOS does have settings to make it shut down/restart on a schedule.  **If**¹ Touch ID is implemented like it is on IOS, then password is always required after a restart.

So, if you set it to reboot at four AM, …

¹I say “if” because my laptop doesn't have touch ID